# horizontal scroll bar not moving the content inside the page in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Hi I have the container div set for displaying horizontal and vertical scroll bar if contents exceeds its size. it the most parent div container which contain divs, and in them swf flash objects (charts)

here is the main parent div definition

```
  <div style="padding: 20px;overflow: auto;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll">

-----all page content with nested divs, flash charts etc.
</div>
```

The above works fine with firefox, so the horizontal and vertical scroll bars come up and when moved the data moves.. but in IE 8 although the scroll bars do come up but on moving them all the content doesnt move, only some of the divs move, more specifically the divs which have flash charts dont move at all.

How is this implemented for IE 8?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got similar problem in IE6.Adding "position:relative" in div's style solved it.